# IE 7 crashes with style position relative

Tags: html, css

Below link code causing IE 7 to Crash when link is clicked , when googled it is saying there is bug in IE 7 
DO there is any work around for this ?

```
<a title="FAQ" style="position:relative;right:235px;top:-55px;" target="_blank"   href="http://www.Google.com/ccp/index.jsp?pg_name=shared/help/page/Somahlep_FAQ_hwtp">READ OUR FAQS</a>
```

Comment: if you remove `position:relative` does it work?

Comment: Yes Its working perfect if i remove Position:Relative tag

Comment: Doesn't crash for me, unless there is more to your test case you're not telling us.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on your point of view.

From the view of a web-developer:

**Don't use that code**

From the point of view as a user:

**Avoid clicking on links in suspicious websites.** And, subsequently, report the website to (among others):

- Symantec: https://submit.symantec.com/antifraud/phish.cgi (Admittedly it's more for phishing than...whatever buggy-hyperlinks could be considered to be).
- Microsoft, I can only speak for IE8 (because I don't have IE7 or lower):

> If you believe you have encountered an unsafe website, you can report it to Microsoft by clicking the Safety button, and then clicking SmartScreen Filter followed by Report Unsafe Website. When you report an unsafe website, some information will be sent to Microsoft including the address of the site you are reporting, and the usage information described above.

(source: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/privacy.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding zoom:1 to the inline style as follows

```
<a title="FAQ" style="position:relative;zoom:1;right:235px;top:-55px;" target="_blank"   href="http://www.Google.com/ccp/index.jsp?pg_name=shared/help/page/Somahlep_FAQ_hwtp">READ OUR FAQS</a>
```

I spent a bloody 4 hours on this until I found out how to reproduce it

You need to have Windows XP SP3 + IE7 + install Microsoft Security Update for Internet Explorer 7 (KB2618444). It is that security update that makes this problem surfaces!

in my case I am using a css instead of an inline style and adding zoom:1 beside position:relative fixed the problem